# is there way to use multiprefix using elasticsearch java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

using ***QueryBuilders.prefixQuery*** i'm trying to get the list of book title that starts with **"L"** or **"J"** is there any way to achieve that?
I know that QueryBuilders.prefixQuery can accept only string like ***boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("bookTitle", "L"));*** is there any othere simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the boolean clause `should` and combine two prefix query one for `L` and one for `J` which will provide your expected search results, means books with starts from either `L` or `J`.

In java code it will look below:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        PrefixQueryBuilder lPrefixQueryBuilder = new PrefixQueryBuilder("title","L");
        PrefixQueryBuilder jPrefixQueryBuilder = new PrefixQueryBuilder("title","J");
        boolQueryBuilder.should(lPrefixQueryBuilder);
        boolQueryBuilder.should(jPrefixQueryBuilder);
```

Comment: is there a simplest way to make it dynamic regardless the number of PrefixQueryBuilder ?

Comment: @MohamedNAOUALI yes, you can simply loop through your prefix clauses :)